# Creating Neo4j relationship while importing from csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j. I have csv file containing data in the format:

```
"from","to","amount","count"  
"Lenin","George","10000","1"  
"Mike","Suriya","4000","3"  
"Mike","Norman","10000","1"  
"George","Lenin","4000","1"
```

Now, I would like to import this csv with relationship so that I can get graph with circular redirection like incase of Lenin and George. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///csv.csv" as row
MERGE (n:Person{name:row.from})
MERGE (m:Person{name:row.to})
MERGE (n)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(m)
ON CREATE SET r.amount = row.amount,
              r.count = row.count
```

check https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/ for more information